# regionprops vs. findContours

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

Is there a way to get the same results for 
    cDist=regionprops(bwImg, 'Area');
and openCV's findContours?

Input image:
[image]

Bw Input image:
[image]

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
dst.convertTo(dst,CV_8U);
cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours_1;
cv::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy_1;
cv::findContours(dst,contours_1,hierarchy_1,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

double maxLabelSize = (dst.rows/4.0) * (dst.cols/6.0);
double minLabelSize = ((dst.rows/40.0) * (dst.cols/60.0));

cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > goodContours;
for (int i = 0; i < contours_1.size(); i++)
{
    double size = cv::contourArea(contours_1[i]);
    if (size < maxLabelSize && size > minLabelSize)
    {
        goodContours.push_back(contours_1[i]);
    }
}

cv::Mat filterContours = cv::Mat::zeros(dst.size(),CV_8UC3);    
for (int i = 0; i < goodContours.size(); i++)
{
    cv::RNG rng(12345);
    cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
    drawContours( filterContours, goodContours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy_1, 0, cv::Point() );
}

cv::imshow( "Contours", filterContours );
cv::waitKey(0);
```

OpenCV result:
[image: OpenCV's result]

Matlab's Version:

```
% Calculate each separated object area
    cDist=regionprops(bwImg, 'Area');
    cDist=[cDist.Area];

    % Label each object
    [bwImgLabeled, ~]=bwlabel(bwImg);

    % Calculate min and max object size based on assumptions
    maxLabelSize = prod(size(imageData)./[4 6]);
    minLabelSize = prod(size(imageData)./[4 6]./10);

    % Find label indices for objects that are too large or too small
    remInd = find(cDist > maxLabelSize);
    remInd = [remInd find(cDist < minLabelSize)];

    % Remove over/undersized objects
    for n=1:length(remInd)
        ri = bwImgLabeled == remInd(n);
        bwImgLabeled(ri) = 0;
    end
```

Matlab's result:
[image: Matlab's result]

Please note the left bottom square is missing from the openCV image.

Comment: is the top (grayscale) image your input image? is the bottom image your matlab result? is the bottom image your aim or do you want contours?!? (I dont know matlabs regionprops function, what does it do?)

Comment: They are both output images,  the top is output from opencv,  the bottom is from matlab,  regionprops is like opencv,  findContours

Comment: what's the problem with openCV output? looks very similar to the matlab output (except the size and some small detail differences around the edges)

Comment: and please post the input image!

Comment: @Micka here i did post it. the original image is raw (Bayer format) image. but I shrink it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV version 3.0 beta has "connectedComponents" function. This function create label image and calculate some regions properties: area, bounding box and centroids.

In case of OpenCV 2.4 you can include connectedcomponents.cpp
from [current OpenCV source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp) to your project and use  "connectedComponentsWithStats" function:

```
nLabels = connectedComponentsWithStats(mask, labelImage, stats, centroids, connectivity, CV_32S);
```

Variables:

- nLabels - number of regions;
- mask - input binary image;
- labelImage - output image with labeled regions;
- stats - region properties (bounding box, area);
- centroids;
- connectivity - regions connectivity (4 or 8).

connectedcomponents.cpp:

```
#include "precomp.hpp"
#include <vector>

namespace cv{
namespace connectedcomponents{

struct NoOp{
    NoOp(){
    }
    void init(int /*labels*/){
    }
    inline
    void operator()(int r, int c, int l){
        (void) r;
        (void) c;
        (void) l;
    }
    void finish(){}
};
struct Point2ui64{
    uint64 x, y;
    Point2ui64(uint64 _x, uint64 _y):x(_x), y(_y){}
};

struct CCStatsOp{
    const _OutputArray* _mstatsv;
    cv::Mat statsv;
    const _OutputArray* _mcentroidsv;
    cv::Mat centroidsv;
    std::vector<Point2ui64> integrals;

    CCStatsOp(OutputArray _statsv, OutputArray _centroidsv): _mstatsv(&_statsv), _mcentroidsv(&_centroidsv){
    }
    inline
    void init(int nlabels){
        _mstatsv->create(cv::Size(CC_STAT_MAX, nlabels), cv::DataType<int>::type);
        statsv = _mstatsv->getMat();
        _mcentroidsv->create(cv::Size(2, nlabels), cv::DataType<double>::type);
        centroidsv = _mcentroidsv->getMat();

        for(int l = 0; l < (int) nlabels; ++l){
            int *row = (int *) &statsv.at<int>(l, 0);
            row[CC_STAT_LEFT] = INT_MAX;
            row[CC_STAT_TOP] = INT_MAX;
            row[CC_STAT_WIDTH] = INT_MIN;
            row[CC_STAT_HEIGHT] = INT_MIN;
            row[CC_STAT_AREA] = 0;
        }
        integrals.resize(nlabels, Point2ui64(0, 0));
    }
    void operator()(int r, int c, int l){
        int *row = &statsv.at<int>(l, 0);
        row[CC_STAT_LEFT] = MIN(row[CC_STAT_LEFT], c);
        row[CC_STAT_WIDTH] = MAX(row[CC_STAT_WIDTH], c);
        row[CC_STAT_TOP] = MIN(row[CC_STAT_TOP], r);
        row[CC_STAT_HEIGHT] = MAX(row[CC_STAT_HEIGHT], r);
        row[CC_STAT_AREA]++;
        Point2ui64 &integral = integrals[l];
        integral.x += c;
        integral.y += r;
    }
    void finish(){
        for(int l = 0; l < statsv.rows; ++l){
            int *row = &statsv.at<int>(l, 0);
            row[CC_STAT_WIDTH] = row[CC_STAT_WIDTH] - row[CC_STAT_LEFT] + 1;
            row[CC_STAT_HEIGHT] = row[CC_STAT_HEIGHT] - row[CC_STAT_TOP] + 1;

            Point2ui64 &integral = integrals[l];
            double *centroid = &centroidsv.at<double>(l, 0);
            double area = ((unsigned*)row)[CC_STAT_AREA];
            centroid[0] = double(integral.x) / area;
            centroid[1] = double(integral.y) / area;
        }
    }
};

//Find the root of the tree of node i
template<typename LabelT>
inline static
LabelT findRoot(const LabelT *P, LabelT i){
    LabelT root = i;
    while(P[root] < root){
        root = P[root];
    }
    return root;
}

//Make all nodes in the path of node i point to root
template<typename LabelT>
inline static
void setRoot(LabelT *P, LabelT i, LabelT root){
    while(P[i] < i){
        LabelT j = P[i];
        P[i] = root;
        i = j;
    }
    P[i] = root;
}

//Find the root of the tree of the node i and compress the path in the process
template<typename LabelT>
inline static
LabelT find(LabelT *P, LabelT i){
    LabelT root = findRoot(P, i);
    setRoot(P, i, root);
    return root;
}

//unite the two trees containing nodes i and j and return the new root
template<typename LabelT>
inline static
LabelT set_union(LabelT *P, LabelT i, LabelT j){
    LabelT root = findRoot(P, i);
    if(i != j){
        LabelT rootj = findRoot(P, j);
        if(root > rootj){
            root = rootj;
        }
        setRoot(P, j, root);
    }
    setRoot(P, i, root);
    return root;
}

//Flatten the Union Find tree and relabel the components
template<typename LabelT>
inline static
LabelT flattenL(LabelT *P, LabelT length){
    LabelT k = 1;
    for(LabelT i = 1; i < length; ++i){
        if(P[i] < i){
            P[i] = P[P[i]];
        }else{
            P[i] = k; k = k + 1;
        }
    }
    return k;
}

//Based on "Two Strategies to Speed up Connected Components Algorithms", the SAUF (Scan array union find) variant
//using decision trees
//Kesheng Wu, et al
//Note: rows are encoded as position in the "rows" array to save lookup times
//reference for 4-way: {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}};//b, d neighborhoods
const int G4[2][2] = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}};//b, d neighborhoods
//reference for 8-way: {{-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -1}};//a, b, c, d neighborhoods
const int G8[4][2] = {{1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, -1}};//a, b, c, d neighborhoods
template<typename LabelT, typename PixelT, typename StatsOp = NoOp >
struct LabelingImpl{
LabelT operator()(const cv::Mat &I, cv::Mat &L, int connectivity, StatsOp &sop){
    CV_Assert(L.rows == I.rows);
    CV_Assert(L.cols == I.cols);
    CV_Assert(connectivity == 8 || connectivity == 4);
    const int rows = L.rows;
    const int cols = L.cols;
    //A quick and dirty upper bound for the maximimum number of labels.  The 4 comes from
    //the fact that a 3x3 block can never have more than 4 unique labels for both 4 & 8-way
    const size_t Plength = 4 * (size_t(rows + 3 - 1)/3) * (size_t(cols + 3 - 1)/3);
    LabelT *P = (LabelT *) fastMalloc(sizeof(LabelT) * Plength);
    P[0] = 0;
    LabelT lunique = 1;
    //scanning phase
    for(int r_i = 0; r_i < rows; ++r_i){
        LabelT * const Lrow = L.ptr<LabelT>(r_i);
        LabelT * const Lrow_prev = (LabelT *)(((char *)Lrow) - L.step.p[0]);
        const PixelT * const Irow = I.ptr<PixelT>(r_i);
        const PixelT * const Irow_prev = (const PixelT *)(((char *)Irow) - I.step.p[0]);
        LabelT *Lrows[2] = {
            Lrow,
            Lrow_prev
        };
        const PixelT *Irows[2] = {
            Irow,
            Irow_prev
        };
        if(connectivity == 8){
            const int a = 0;
            const int b = 1;
            const int c = 2;
            const int d = 3;
            const bool T_a_r = (r_i - G8[a][0]) >= 0;
            const bool T_b_r = (r_i - G8[b][0]) >= 0;
            const bool T_c_r = (r_i - G8[c][0]) >= 0;
            for(int c_i = 0; Irows[0] != Irow + cols; ++Irows[0], c_i++){
                if(!*Irows[0]){
                    Lrow[c_i] = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                Irows[1] = Irow_prev + c_i;
                Lrows[0] = Lrow + c_i;
                Lrows[1] = Lrow_prev + c_i;
                const bool T_a = T_a_r && (c_i + G8[a][1]) >= 0   && *(Irows[G8[a][0]] + G8[a][1]);
                const bool T_b = T_b_r                            && *(Irows[G8[b][0]] + G8[b][1]);
                const bool T_c = T_c_r && (c_i + G8[c][1]) < cols && *(Irows[G8[c][0]] + G8[c][1]);
                const bool T_d =          (c_i + G8[d][1]) >= 0   && *(Irows[G8[d][0]] + G8[d][1]);

                //decision tree
                if(T_b){
                    //copy(b)
                    *Lrows[0] = *(Lrows[G8[b][0]] + G8[b][1]);
                }else{//not b
                    if(T_c){
                        if(T_a){
                            //copy(c, a)
                            *Lrows[0] = set_union(P, *(Lrows[G8[c][0]] + G8[c][1]), *(Lrows[G8[a][0]] + G8[a][1]));
                        }else{
                            if(T_d){
                                //copy(c, d)
                                *Lrows[0] = set_union(P, *(Lrows[G8[c][0]] + G8[c][1]), *(Lrows[G8[d][0]] + G8[d][1]));
                            }else{
                                //copy(c)
                                *Lrows[0] = *(Lrows[G8[c][0]] + G8[c][1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{//not c
                        if(T_a){
                            //copy(a)
                            *Lrows[0] = *(Lrows[G8[a][0]] + G8[a][1]);
                        }else{
                            if(T_d){
                                //copy(d)
                                *Lrows[0] = *(Lrows[G8[d][0]] + G8[d][1]);
                            }else{
                                //new label
                                *Lrows[0] = lunique;
                                P[lunique] = lunique;
                                lunique = lunique + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            //B & D only
            const int b = 0;
            const int d = 1;
            const bool T_b_r = (r_i - G4[b][0]) >= 0;
            for(int c_i = 0; Irows[0] != Irow + cols; ++Irows[0], c_i++){
                if(!*Irows[0]){
                    Lrow[c_i] = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                Irows[1] = Irow_prev + c_i;
                Lrows[0] = Lrow + c_i;
                Lrows[1] = Lrow_prev + c_i;
                const bool T_b = T_b_r                            && *(Irows[G4[b][0]] + G4[b][1]);
                const bool T_d =          (c_i + G4[d][1]) >= 0   && *(Irows[G4[d][0]] + G4[d][1]);
                if(T_b){
                    if(T_d){
                        //copy(d, b)
                        *Lrows[0] = set_union(P, *(Lrows[G4[d][0]] + G4[d][1]), *(Lrows[G4[b][0]] + G4[b][1]));
                    }else{
                        //copy(b)
                        *Lrows[0] = *(Lrows[G4[b][0]] + G4[b][1]);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(T_d){
                        //copy(d)
                        *Lrows[0] = *(Lrows[G4[d][0]] + G4[d][1]);
                    }else{
                        //new label
                        *Lrows[0] = lunique;
                        P[lunique] = lunique;
                        lunique = lunique + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //analysis
    LabelT nLabels = flattenL(P, lunique);
    sop.init(nLabels);

    for(int r_i = 0; r_i < rows; ++r_i){
        LabelT *Lrow_start = L.ptr<LabelT>(r_i);
        LabelT *Lrow_end = Lrow_start + cols;
        LabelT *Lrow = Lrow_start;
        for(int c_i = 0; Lrow != Lrow_end; ++Lrow, ++c_i){
            const LabelT l = P[*Lrow];
            *Lrow = l;
            sop(r_i, c_i, l);
        }
    }

    sop.finish();
    fastFree(P);

    return nLabels;
}//End function LabelingImpl operator()

};//End struct LabelingImpl
}//end namespace connectedcomponents

//L's type must have an appropriate depth for the number of pixels in I
template<typename StatsOp>
static
int connectedComponents_sub1(const cv::Mat &I, cv::Mat &L, int connectivity, StatsOp &sop){
CV_Assert(L.channels() == 1 && I.channels() == 1);
CV_Assert(connectivity == 8 || connectivity == 4);

int lDepth = L.depth();
int iDepth = I.depth();
using connectedcomponents::LabelingImpl;
//warn if L's depth is not sufficient?

CV_Assert(iDepth == CV_8U || iDepth == CV_8S);

if(lDepth == CV_8U){
    return (int) LabelingImpl<uchar, uchar, StatsOp>()(I, L, connectivity, sop);
}else if(lDepth == CV_16U){
    return (int) LabelingImpl<ushort, uchar, StatsOp>()(I, L, connectivity, sop);
}else if(lDepth == CV_32S){
    //note that signed types don't really make sense here and not being able to use unsigned matters for scientific projects
    //OpenCV: how should we proceed?  .at<T> typechecks in debug mode
    return (int) LabelingImpl<int, uchar, StatsOp>()(I, L, connectivity, sop);
}

CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "unsupported label/image type");
return -1;
}

}

int cv::connectedComponents(InputArray _img, OutputArray _labels, int connectivity, int ltype){
const cv::Mat img = _img.getMat();
_labels.create(img.size(), CV_MAT_DEPTH(ltype));
cv::Mat labels = _labels.getMat();
connectedcomponents::NoOp sop;
if(ltype == CV_16U){
    return connectedComponents_sub1(img, labels, connectivity, sop);
}else if(ltype == CV_32S){
    return connectedComponents_sub1(img, labels, connectivity, sop);
}else{
    CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "the type of labels must be 16u or 32s");
    return 0;
}
}

int cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(InputArray _img, OutputArray _labels, OutputArray statsv,
                                 OutputArray centroids, int connectivity, int ltype)
{
const cv::Mat img = _img.getMat();
_labels.create(img.size(), CV_MAT_DEPTH(ltype));
cv::Mat labels = _labels.getMat();
connectedcomponents::CCStatsOp sop(statsv, centroids);
if(ltype == CV_16U){
    return connectedComponents_sub1(img, labels, connectivity, sop);
}else if(ltype == CV_32S){
    return connectedComponents_sub1(img, labels, connectivity, sop);
}else{
    CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "the type of labels must be 16u or 32s");
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to obtain the connected component labels (works **similar** to bwlabel of matlab). Opencv findContours and bwlabel of matlab are different. Take some time to work on it. In the mean time the below code will temporarily solve your problem. (To familiarize opencv findcontours - try playing with Contour retrieval mode and Contour approximation method - [Ref](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours)).

```
void bwlabelMat(Mat &binary, vector<vector <Point>> &lablidx, int &labels)
{
    if (binary.type() != CV_32F)
    {
        cout << "convert the input image to CV_32FC1 with 0 & 1 as pixel elements" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // starts at 2 because 0,1 are used already
    int labelCount = 2; 

    for (int y = 0; y < binary.rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < binary.cols; x++)
        {
            if (1 == (int)binary.at<float>(y, x))
            {

                Rect rect;
                floodFill(binary, Point(x, y), Scalar(labelCount), &rect, Scalar(0), Scalar(0), 4);
                vector <Point>  blob;
                for (int i = rect.y; i < (rect.y + rect.height); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = rect.x; j < (rect.x + rect.width); j++)
                    {
                        if (labelCount == (int)binary.at<float>(i, j))
                        {
                            blob.push_back(Point(j, i));
                        }
                    }
                }

                lablidx.push_back(blob);

                labelCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < binary.rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < binary.cols; x++)
        {
            if ((0 != (int)binary.at<float>(y, x)) && (1 != (int)binary.at<float>(y, x)))
                binary.at<float>(y, x) = binary.at<float>(y, x) - 1.0;

        }
    }
    labelCount = labelCount - 2;
    labels = labelCount;
}
```

Regarding : regionprops of matlab : Opencv as such straight forward doesn't have regionprops equivalent but still there is scope to re-produce the exact results as it just involves maths behind. I am sharing you a link as I cannot completely post the code here. I have referred this python implementation and reproduced in c++. It works fine. Go ahead.

Link : [contour features](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/04/contour-features.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using cvblobs for labeling,  thanks.  I did play with findcontours flags,  but no luck,  i think the problem is with how i use findcontours,  do i have to do canny edge detection before?

Comment: No. Edge detectors are not necessary. I am not sure about cvblobs, but are you sure the number of labels returned from matlab and cvblobs are same ? If not try the above code as I had success in number of labels from both matlab and the above function. Give a check to the thresholding steps too as Matlab's otsu differs from opencv.

Comment: I have post the input image as well. I will try the code later on